# mongo DB always update first document

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a posts collection that has **array of likes**.I want to **push** object into likes array if **user have not liked** and **pull if user has liked the post**.I test  my API but it always update first document of collection though I provided **postId** of other document.

schema.js

```
likes: [
    {
      userId: String,
      isNotified: {
        type: Boolean,
        default: false,
      },
      email: String,
      types: String,
    },
  ],
```

API

```
router.post("/like", (req, res) => {
      postModel.find(
      {
        "_Id": req.body.postId,
        "likes.userId": req.body.userId,
      },
      (err, doc) => {
        // console.log(doc)
       if (!doc.length) {
          postModel.updateOne(
            { "_Id": req.body.postId,},
            {
              $push: {
                likes: {
                  userId: req.body.userId,
                  email: req.body.email,
                  // types: req.body.types,
                },
              },
            },
            (err, doc) => {
               res.send("like");
            }
          );
        } else {
          // console.log("pull")
          postModel.find(
            {
              "_Id": req.body.postId,
              "likes.userId": req.body.userId,
            },
            (err, doc) => {
              doc.map((e) => {
                e.likes.map((x) => {
                  if (x.userId == req.body.userId) {
                    postModel.updateOne(
                      {
                        "_Id": req.body.postId,
                        "likes.userId": req.body.userId,
                      },
                      {
                        $pull: {
                          likes: {
                            userId: req.body.userId,
                            email:req.body.email
                          },
                        },
                      },
                      (err, doc) => {
                        
                          res.send("unlike");
                        
                      }
                    );
                  }
                });
              });
            }
          );
        }
        // res.send(doc);
      }
      
    );
  // });
});
```

postman request

```
           {
               "email":"mahima@gmail.com",
               "types":"like",
                "postId":"6312c2d1842444a707b6902f",
                 "userId":"631452d0e1c2acf0be28ce43"
      
         }
```

How to fix this,suggest an advice.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your schema has a `postId` field. Shouldn't you match on that instead of `_id`

Comment: Oh,I mistakenly type postId too,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if I undrestand the logic, but here are couple of things that I think you can improve:

1. You are using `find` method to get a single document, you should use `findOne` method which return a single document (if exists) and not an array of documents. But in general when you have the `_id` value of a document, it's better to just use `findById` method which is much faster.
2. When you `find` a document, you can just modify it and call it's `save` method to write your changes to the database, there is no need to use `updateOne`. (please note that *partital update* has many advantages but in your case they don't seem necessary, you can read about it online.)

your API code can be something like this:

```
router.post("/like", (req, res) => {
  const postId = req.body.postId
  const userId = req.body.userId

  postModel.findById(postId) // get the post
    .then(post => {
      if (post) { // check if post exists

        // check if user has already liked the post 
        if (post.likes.find(like => like.userId == userId)){
          // user has already liked the post, so we want to
          // remove it from likes (unlike the post). 

          // I know this is not the best way to remove an item 
          // from an array, but it's easy to understand and it
          // also removes all duplications (just in case).
          post.likes = post.likes.filter(like => like.userId != userId)

          // save the modified post document and return
          return post.save(_ => {
            // send success message to client
            res.send("unlike")
          })

        } else {
          // user has not liked the post, so we want to add a
          // like object to post's likes array
          post.likes.push({
            userId: userId,
            email: req.body.email // you can other properties here
          })

          // save the modified post document and return
          return post.save(_ => {
            // send success message to client
            res.send("like")
          })
        }
      } else { // in case post doesn't exist
        res.status(404).send("post not found.")
      }
    })
    .catch(err => {
      // you can handle errors here
      console.log(err.message)
      res.send("an error occurred")
    })
})
```

I didn't run the code, but it should work.